# jQuery to display value of row input and checkbox status

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Please see this fiddle...
http://jsfiddle.net/sM8sb/1/

jQuery syntax is:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[name^="treated"]', function () {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    calculateRow(row);
});

function calculateRow(row) {
    if ($("table.authors-list").find('input[name^="treated"]').is(':checked')) {
        var product = row.find('input[name^="product"]').val();
        alert(product + ' checked');
    } else {
        var product = row.find('input[name^="product"]').val();
        alert(product + ' unchecked');
    }

}
```

What I am wanting is that when I check the checkbox of a row, it display the value of the product input for that row and the status 'checked'. when I uncheck it it shows the same but with unchecked.

I am not sure on the onload/ondomready option for the jQuery on jsfiddle.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `calculateRow`, you're always selecting `$("table.authors-list").find('input[name^="treated"]')` which will yield *all* input elements that have a name starting with "treated". Your `.is` will go to the *checked* condition every time *any* checkbox in that selection is checked.

You'll want to use something like `row.find('input[name^="treated"]')` instead. Or `row.find(':checkbox')`, or just pass `this` from the click listener as an input parameter to `calculateRow` ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TteAM/)).

By the way, you might find the code a bit easier to write if you start using classes instead of inspecting names. [You could end up with something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/sq3At/).

Comment: Thanks David. your fiddle doesn't work on my side though, alert not showing. Thanks. I will def look into classes. is it my fsfiddle jquery settings?

Comment: Sorry correction, this is working in firefox but not IE(10). any ideas why?

Comment: @Smudger: It appears jQuery 1.10.1 won't load in IE 10 jsFiddle. I'm not sure if it's an issue with IE 10 or jsFiddle. Change the library to 1.9.1 and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sM8sb/2/)

You must find checkbox in current row, not in whole table.

```
if (row.find('input[name^="treated"]').is(':checked')) {
```

Comment: Thanks jQuery00, the fiddle doesn't show alert though, something to do with the onload or jquery settings for fiddle? thanks

Comment: Sorry man, as per comment to David works in firefox but not IE10? any suggestions?

Comment: It's works good for me, alert fire when I click at the checkbox.

Comment: Thanks Jquery, greatly appreciated. David just pipped you for answer based on time otherwise 100%. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is unnecessary to find the row to do what you want.  Your code would be more efficient as follows:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[name^="treated"]', function () {
    calculateRow($(this));
});

function calculateRow(checkbox) {
    var product = checkbox.prev().val();
    alert(product + (checkbox.prop('checked') ? ' checked' : ' unchecked'));
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sM8sb/6/)

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
    $('input[name^="treated"]').change(function () {
        var this_checkbox = $(this);
        if (this_checkbox.is(':checked')) {
            var product = this_checkbox.closest('tr').find('input[name^="product"]').val();
            alert(product + ' checked');
        }
        else {
            var product = this_checkbox.closest('tr').find('input[name^="product"]').val();
            alert(product + ' unchecked');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

The answers already given here work perfectly well.This is just my take on it.

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[name^="treated"]', function () {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    calculateRow(row, $(this));
});

function calculateRow(row, chkBox) {
    var checked = chkBox.is(':checked'),
        product = row.find('input[name^="product"]').val();

    alert(product + ((checked)?' checked': ' unchecked'));

}
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but it seems rather unnecessary to pass both parameters.